# Git archive including the actual repository?

Tags: git, git-archive

I need to create an archive of my Git project, ignoring and leaving out files specified by `.gitignore`, but including the actual `.git` repository folder. Simply running `git archive master` leaves out the `.git` folder.

Is there a way to make `git archive` include the `.git` folder but still ignore files specified by `.gitignore`?

Comment: You can just copy the `.git` folder alone and later checkout HEAD to get your files. Or you simply transfer it by fetching from it as a remote repository.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like doing something like

```
# copy over all project files except for those ignored
git clone /path/to/repository /path/to/output 
# create a tar.gz archive of the project location
tar czvf projectExport.tar.gz /path/to/output
# remove the cloned directory
rm -fr /path/to/output
```

gets the job done. It's not the most beautiful solution in the world, but it looks like it works.

Comment: This doesn't take .gitignore into account.

Answer (score 16):

Since `git archive` just produces a tar archive you can work on that file with `tar` directly.

```
$ git archive HEAD > tar.tar
$ tar -rf tar.tar .git
```

tar's `-r` option appends the files given to the archive being worked on (specified after `-f`). Check tar's man page for the intimidating list of features tar has.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as it takes into account .gitignore.

Answer (score 0):

`git bundle` is a newer command which allows the creation of an archive to be shared with a remote machine.  The `git bundle` is more flexible in that it allows incremental updates and merging of different branches.  However, you can create a bundle that use a complete specification, such as `master`.

A downside is that the remote machine also needs git.  The bundle is a 'pack' file and the files would need to be 'checked out' from the bundle to create a working directory on the remote (as opposed to tar).  The set of machines with `tar && git` and `!tar && !git` is much larger than `tar && !git` and `!tar && git`.  Ie, the machine likely has both or neither.  Especially as you would intend to build source.

For Windows machines which likely have neither.  You can use the 'zip' form.

```
git archive -o ../archive.zip --format=zip HEAD
zip -ur ../archive.zip .git/
```

.. and you have my condolences.